ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable | Changing dataframe values using .at
I'm writing a function that recommends 5 products. I'm using cosine similarity as similarity metrics and I'm using arrays of length 2 that is comprised of t-SNE feature values for each product, e.g. x-coordinate and y-coordinate.
My input is the name of the product, and I want to iterate through the dataframe, calculate the cosine similarity between the input product and each product, and then set the cosine similarity to the 'dist' column for each row via df.at. The shape of point_1 is (1,2) and the shape of point_2 is (2,).
However, when I'm calling the function using an example, I get the following error message: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
How should I modify my function to address this issue?
def yesstyle_recommender(product, label, df):

    #filter df by label
    filtered_df = df[df['label'] == label].reset_index().drop('index', axis = 1)

    #extract the product name, has to exactly match
    myItem = filtered_df[filtered_df['name'].str.contains(product, case=False)]

    if myItem.empty:
        print("Product not found.")
        return None

    # extract tsne values for the target item
    X = myItem['X'].values
    Y = myItem['Y'].values
    
    point_1 = np.array([X,Y]).T
    
    #instantiate 'dist' column to 0
    filtered_df['dist'] = 0.0

    #iterate through df and calculate cos sim
    for i in range(len(filtered_df)):
        point_2 = np.array([filtered_df['X'][i], filtered_df['Y'][i]])
        filtered_df.at[i, 'dist'] = np.dot(point_1, point_2) / (norm(point_1) * norm(point_2))

    #sort by 'dist' in descending order
    filtered_df = filtered_df.sort_values('dist', ascending=False)

    top_5_recommendations = filtered_df[['product','brand','price','dist']]

    return top_5_recommendations

#call function using an example product
yesstyle_recommender('Relief Sun','spf', yesstyle)



You should provide a [mre]

The error you get comes from the fact that X and Y are both arrays with a single element but you get a (2,1) array, which isn't suitable for element-wise operations later in your code. You need to properly handle the shape of the arrays and ensure that the points you compare in the cosine similarity computation are of the correct shape. Unless your data looks entirely different from the sample I created, this is what you should do:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.linalg import norm

def yesstyle_recommender(product, label, df):
    filtered_df = df[df['label'] == label].reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
    myItem = filtered_df[filtered_df['name'].str.contains(product, case=False)]

    if myItem.empty:
        print("Product not found.")
        return None

    X = myItem['X'].values[0]
    Y = myItem['Y'].values[0]

    point_1 = np.array([X, Y])
    filtered_df['dist'] = 0.0

    for i in range(len(filtered_df)):
        point_2 = np.array([filtered_df['X'][i], filtered_df['Y'][i]])
        filtered_df.at[i, 'dist'] = np.dot(point_1, point_2) / (norm(point_1) * norm(point_2))

    filtered_df = filtered_df.sort_values('dist', ascending=False)
    top_5_recommendations = filtered_df[['name', 'brand', 'price', 'dist']].head(5)

    return top_5_recommendations

data = {
    'name': ['Relief Sun', 'Sun Stick', 'Moisture Cream', 'UV Shield', 'Sun Gel', 'SPF Lotion'],
    'label': ['spf', 'spf', 'spf', 'spf', 'spf', 'spf'],
    'brand': ['BrandA', 'BrandB', 'BrandC', 'BrandD', 'BrandE', 'BrandF'],
    'price': [15.99, 20.99, 25.99, 30.99, 35.99, 40.99],
    'X': [1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
    'Y': [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5]
}

yesstyle = pd.DataFrame(data)

recommendations = yesstyle_recommender('Relief Sun', 'spf', yesstyle)
print(recommendations)

which gives
             name   brand  price      dist
0      Relief Sun  BrandA  15.99  1.000000
3       UV Shield  BrandD  30.99  0.995893
1       Sun Stick  BrandB  20.99  0.989949
2  Moisture Cream  BrandC  25.99  0.989949
4         Sun Gel  BrandE  35.99  0.989949

